# What is the best image viewer for mac which allows me to navigate through images in the current folder using keyboard?

Tags: macos, image-viewer

What is the best fast image viewer for mac which allows me to navigate through images in the current folder using keyboard? So, basically I open one image and then using e.g. arrow keys navigate through all images in the folder. Ideally free. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what QuickLook does. Press spacebar while navigating in the Finder.

Comment: why downvoted. it refers to software and issues with it. i was trying to find an alternative software for image previewing - the answer from @AshvinMonpara helps me a lot and you downvoted him as well

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Xee is a lightweight, fast and convenient image viewer and browser. It is designed to be a serious tool for image viewing and management, with a sleek and powerful interface.

https://code.google.com/p/xee/

Comment: This looks a lot like spam.

Comment: @AshvinMonpara: Welcome, and thanks for helping with this question.  The reason your answer was downvoted and commented is that it looks like what is considered spam on Super User.  The purpose of the site is to build a knowledgebase of questions and solutions, so we're looking for more of a "solution" with software recommendations than just a link and some "marketing" words (and if you are associated with the product, you need to disclose that).  For guidance, read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.

Comment: Actually, the question is off-topic, so improving your answer is probably not a good use of your time.